# Changing the output directory for Quarto projects in Rstudio

Tags: directory, r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

I am transitioning from using Rmarkdown to Quarto files within R projects. When using Rmarkdown I was able to direct my output file in a specific directory to reduce clutter.

For example, my project structure usually takes the form:

```
$
│ demo_proj.Rproj
│ _quarto.yml
│
├─-quarto
│    test_render.qmd
│
├─-output
│    test_render.pdf
│
└─-data
     cars.csv
```

In Rmarkdown I could just insert the following lines in the YAML and the knitted file would be placed in the output directory (as above).

```
knit: (function(input, ...) {
    rmarkdown::render(
      input,
      output_dir = "../output"
    )
  })
```

Is there a similar possible solution when using Quarto projects?

I've tried adding:

```
project:
  title: "r_thesis"
  output-dir: output
```

to the `_quarto.yml`, which sorts of works but with two annoying consequences.

1. The knitted file is saved in a directory named `quarto` within the `output` folder
2. The local host browser in which the knitted file should be open cannot find the file, meaning I have to open them manually every time I knit.

Does anyone know of any solution to this very minor but annoying problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you rendering in pdf, you can specify a `latex-output-dir`.

For instance, if you use the following YAML header, the `.pdf` file will be saved inside a `_rendered` folder.

```
project:
  title: "r_thesis"

format:
  pdf:
    latex-output-dir: _rendered
format:
  pdf:
    latex-output-dir: _rendered
```